# I need help understanding how to refresh cache for a place id

Tags: google-reviews

I have installed a Everest GPlaces Business Reviews and have found the place id that is required to be added.  But it comes back Saying:

The provided Place ID is no longer valid. Please refresh cached Place IDs as per https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-id#save-id

I have read this but I have no idea where to add a field they talk about and am totally stuck.  All the reviews plugins have this place id and I don't know what to do from here.

Hoping for some help with what to do.  In basic language.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert; I ran into this problem myself and to my knowledge it seems like reviews can't be pulled easily with most plugins, if the GMB is set up as anything other than a location with a physical address.

Instead of the Places API you'd want to use the My Business API... although if you are using a plugin (and don't want to add a physical location to your GMB) you're stuck.

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted, it's correct. The API simply fails if you don't have a business with a brick and mortar headquarters that you advertise (because, as we all know, service businesses where you work remotely or travel to work at the client location NEVER EVER HAPPEN /s ). This is Google's choice and as of this writing there is no working solution to this issue.